# How to avoid information message of sqlcmd?

Tags: linux, sql-server, odbc, unixodbc

I'm writing script to connect database & execute store procedures, which works fine. But sqlcmd prints extra information message/ invalid characters to command line. Sqlcmd version 13.0.0000.0 Linux is used.

Refer following error message, for tryouts I had created sample script

```
DATE: 17 Aug 16  TIME: 08:04:02
1> 2> hi
1>
```

Sample script,

```
date '+DATE: %d %h %y  TIME: %H:%M:%S'
sqlcmd $1 -D -U<dbo> -P<password> -S<db> << EOF
print 'hi'
go
EOF
```

I'm not getting why `1> 2>` message gets display. How to avoid information message/invalid characters of sqlcmd?

Comment: 1> is std out and 2> is std err. Maybe you could set nocount on or pipe the results to null?

Comment: Thanks @RobertGannon, According me `set nocount on` is use to avoid 'x row affected' messages and this doesn't have impact on 1> 2> error messages.

Comment: @Robert1> 2> message are not stdout & stderr. These are prompting number used by sqlcmd command prompt, it shows how many sql sentences pending for execution. (after go terminator sentence it will get executed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlcmd is command line utility & `1> 2>` messages are prompt message. To avoid prompt message you have to specify input through input file.

Use **-i** switch to give input file. e.x. `sqlcmd -i input file -D -U<dbo> -P<password> -S<db>`.

Additional info, to avoid command line error message you can update flag using -m 0(default)/1. This switch avoid command line error message e.g. database changed message.